# Jquery event function trigger once despite of multiple time attach

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i do this

html

```
   <button id="onclickpopupmenu">Test</button>
   <button id="popupmenuok"></button>
```

javascript:

```
$("#onclickpopupmenu").bind("click",function(){

  alert("this can execute multiple times")
  $("#popmenuok").bind("click",function(){
    alert("this has to be triggered only once eventhough the parent event trigger multiple times")
  })
})
```

Please help me...

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jsVkx/1/ check the console

Comment: Except that there is a spelling mistake in `popupmenuok` and `popmenuok`

Comment: The problem is my inner event triggers as much timee  as the outer event triggers.

Comment: you want it to trigger as many times as the parent event or the event should be triggered only once

Comment: Ya inner event has to be triggered only for once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only bind the handler once:

```
var popupmenuBound = false;

$("#onclickpopupmenu").bind("click",function(){
  alert("this can execute multiple times");
  if (!popupmenuBound) {
    $("#popupmenuok").bind("click",function(){
      alert("this has to be triggered only once eventhough the parent event trigger multiple times");
    });
    popupmenuBound = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to potentially interpret what you want.

The first is multiple clicks on the first button, which results in a single - but persistent (it reacts to every click) - event handler on the second button. To do that you could do this:

```
$('#onclickpopupmenu').click(function() {
    // alert
    $('#popupmenuok').off('click').on('click', function() {
        // alert
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rHwDH/)

The second is multiple clicks on the first button, and for each click on that you get a one-time event handler on the second button. So if you click the first button once, then click the second button, you get an alert, but clicking the second button a second time does nothing. To do that:

```
$('#onclickpopupmenu').click(function() {
    // alert
    $('#popupmenuok').off('click').one('click', function() {
        // alert
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rHwDH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#onclickpopupmenu").bind("click",function(){
  alert("this can execute multiple times");
});

$("#popupmenuok").one("click",function(){
  alert("this has to be triggered only once eventhough the parent event trigger multiple times");
});
```